Try Catch block issue. Selenium C#
I am trying to automate a website but I am having an issue. My code is jumping from the try block directly to the catch block even though I set the attribute names (Xpath) correctly and I have set wait functions. For some reason, It just keeps jumping into a catch block and calling my Captcha function.
    public void scrapping()
    {
        WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
        int retryCount = 0;
        const int maxRetries = 3;

        for (int i = 0; i < currentPage; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                IWebElement chkbox = wait1.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("checkboxCol")));
                wait1.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(chkbox)).Click();
                IWebElement next = wait1.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"searchResults\"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]")));
                wait1.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(next)).Click();
                
                wait1.Until(ExpectedConditions.StalenessOf(next));
                wait1.Until(ExpectedConditions.StalenessOf(chkbox));
                retryCount = 0; // Reset retry count on success
            }
            catch (WebDriverException ex) when (ex.Message.Contains("disconnected"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Browser was manually closed. Aborting the test.");
                Assert.Fail("Browser was manually closed.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                retryCount++;
                if (retryCount >= maxRetries)
                {
                    Assert.Fail("Failed after multiple retries: " + ex.Message);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Captcha detected or unexpected error. Retrying...");
                    Captcha();
                    i--; // Retry the current iteration
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public void Captcha()
    {
        string API = "TBD";
        Console.WriteLine("Solving captcha...");
        TwoCaptcha solver = new TwoCaptcha(""); // API goes here
        HCaptcha captcha = new HCaptcha();
        captcha.SetSiteKey("eTBD");
        captcha.SetUrl("https://2captcha.com/demo/hcaptcha");

        try
        {
            solver.Solve(captcha).Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("Captcha solved: " + captcha.Code);
            IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
            js.ExecuteScript($"document.getElementsByName('h-captcha-response')[0].value = '{captcha.Code}';");
        }
        catch (AggregateException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error occurred: " + e.InnerExceptions.First().Message);
        }
    }

}

}
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

What's the exception and which line of code produces the exception?

@David Captcha detected or unexpected error. Retrying...
Solving captcha...
Error occurred: ERROR_WRONG_USER_KEY
Captcha detected or unexpected error. Retrying...
Solving captcha...
Error occurred: ERROR_WRONG_USER_KEY -- It looks like somewhere in my Try block fails to locate the path and jumps into (Exception Ex) and jumps to the Captcha(); function. I am looking at my browser and it takes a few seconds for the page to fully load but nothing abnormal happens. In my head, the wait function shouldve just done the trick. Did that answer your question? I am new to Selenium.

It sounds like ERROR_WRONG_USER_KEY is the main clue here then.  You may also want to check any other information on the exception, any inner exceptions, etc.  You'll also want to determine which specific operation is producing the exception.  I'm assuming those "TBD" strings are just placeholders in the question to not reveal actual API keys to the world.  But if those are your actual values then that may certainly explain why the key is wrong.

Please [edit] your question to include the exception message and stack trace. Additionally, please indicate which line of code is throwing the exception.
